# Allow attaching files but not editing Note text

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a basic need to protect the integrity of note text in my system; specifically, once a note has been created, no CSR should be able to edit it (higher levels, maybe). Ideally, it should be immutable once created, but I'll allow the CSR that created it to edit it if that's what's necessary; the big deal is that nobody else should have that access.

The basic role permission that enables this is the Write permission of the Note entity. By setting this to "No Access" but still granting access to Create and Append, users can still write new Notes on any Entity they can "Append To" from a form where the notes exist as a subgrid, but they cannot edit any existing Note.

There are, however, two problems with this. First, I lose the "Add New Note" button in the Ribbon. Not a huge deal but it does force the user to add Notes using the inline editor of the subgrid. The bigger deal is that I lose the Attach File button. CSRs still need to be able to attach files, even if they can't edit notes once created.

Is there a way to do what I need?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way doing it with JavaScript on load of your form..just disable the edit of your note with some condition..

Comment: It's funny how the go-to answer for making pretty much any change to a quarter-million-dollar system's basic behaviors is to throw away a chunk of its built-in features and spend several programmer-days redeveloping that piece to do almost the same thing. Thank you Microsoft; yet another example of molding the workplace to your exacting process standards by fighting every effort to do it another way, tooth and nail.

Comment: +1 for clearity of question but mostly for the sharp and well formulated observation on CRM properties. I second @GregOks emotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only GUI protection you're looking for, you might simply set the field to not editable from on load script.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing, so +1 and tick.